# Convert MeSH term to drugbank ID

Tags: public-databases, drugs

I have set of annotated term of drugs extracted from [PubTator](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/research/pubtator/) those drugs are annotated in form of MeSH terms. I would like to map them into drugbank ID. I do search the the MeSH term i find the reference to the drug and link to the drugbank. But not any database as such. How do i map the MeSH term to the drugbank ID.?

My small dataset.

```
Terms         MESH
1        ara-C MESH:D003561
2 mitoxantrone MESH:D008942
3    etoposide MESH:D005047
4  fludarabine MESH:C024352
5   gemtuzumab MESH:C406061
6   ozogamicin            -
```

As an example of one of the drug I would give this drug "gemtuzumab"

```
DB00056 Gemtuzumab ozogamicin   Myeloid cell surface antigen CD33   target
```

So i want to map the above drugs into drugbank ID and add the information such as the class which is here target or it can be a transporter or enzyme etc.

The issue is there is no common ID between the drug MEsH and the drug-bank ID.

Any suggestion or help would be highly appreciated if anyone can cite me some resources.

---

*PubTrator description from the website*

PubTator Central (PTC) is a Web-based system providing automatic annotations of biomedical concepts such as genes and mutations in PubMed abstracts and PMC full-text articles.